# How can I determine a state with a given zip code in Stata?

Tags: stata

Currently, my line of code is really long and I was curious to know if there was a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: And the code in question is?

Comment: Right now I'm just using if/replace for all 50 states

Comment: Yes, there is a more efficient way. But this isn't a guessing game. I am now not even clear whether you mean one line of code, 50 lines of code, or what.

Answer (score 1):

As Nick has pointed out your question is missing most of the information that would make it answerable. [Please read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info), and add more information to your question.

In the meantime, a useful approach is to merge your zipcode data with a dataframe (or dataset) with the state-zipcode link in it.

```
* first you need to get the zipcode data from somewhere. 
* Here is one way:
!wget "https://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/maps-data/data/rel/zcta_county_rel_10.txt"

* now put this data in a frame
frame create zctaFrame
frame zctaFrame{
    import delimited "zcta_county_rel_10.txt"
}

* now I'm making up a dataset (share some of yours with dataex from ssc

input str10 name zip
"sam" 55901
"sasha" 84101
"saul" 84111
end

frlink 1:1 zip, frame(zctaFrame zcta5)
frget state, from(zctaFrame)
```

If this doesn't match what you're trying to do, please add more detail to the question.